# Easy and Best way to configure log4j in EAP 7.2.0 Java Web Application

Tags: web-applications, jboss, log4j, log4j2, jboss7.x

I am having a Java Web Application. I deployed it in Jboss EAP7.2.0 and it is working fine. Now, I want to add log4j to the application and store logs in a specific folder.
Now, I am having `log4j2.xml` in `EAP7.2.0>standalone>deloyments` and I have added the path of log4j2.xml in `EAP7.2.0>bin>stanalone.conf.bat`.
But log files are not getting generated.

Please help me with the easy and best way of implementing dynamic logging of log4j with the above web app and Jboss.

These are the log4j wars I am using `log4j-api-2.17.1`, `log4j-core-2.17.1`

Comment: What does the setting in your `standalone.conf.bat` look like?

Comment: set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS -DLogFramework=log4j2 -Dlog4j.configurationFile=`FilePath`"

Comment: That looks right. I don't know what `LogFramework`, but likely not relevant. Are you using log4j2 loggers or some other logging facade?